# Is version mandatory while creating an Azure VM using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-vm

So I have been working with terraform since last 3 weeks and have been trying to use it to create self hosted GitHub Actions runners in our Azure account.

We have a shared windows VM image in Azure Compute Gallery that I'm planning to use as base image for the GA runner. I have noticed that these shared windows VM images do not generally have any ***versions*** attached to them they just have a publisher, offer and SKU attached.

I also verified by creating a new image from a VM to check if somebody missed attaching the version to the VM, but no shared images do not really have a version attached.

Yeah they do have versions but it is not attached as it is for Microsoft Platform Images.

Example of a shared image:

[image]

Now I found that in terraform, runners can be created by using both: `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` and `azurerm_virtual_machine` resources.

I used both of them to test the runner creation, below are the terraform code used:

```
data "azurerm_shared_image" "win19_gold_image" {
  provider            = azurerm.gi
  name                = "Windows-2019_base"
  gallery_name        = data.azurerm_shared_image_gallery.cap_win_gold_image_gallery.name
  resource_group_name = "gi-rg"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "win_runners_gold_image_based" {
  provider              = azurerm.og
  name                  = "ga-win-gold-1"
  location              = "East US"
  count                 = "1" # if I need to increase the number of VMs.
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.dts_rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.azure_win_runner_gold_nic[count.index].id,]
  vm_size               = "Standard_D4ads_v5"

  delete_os_disk_on_termination = true
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.identifier[0].publisher
    offer     = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.identifier[0].offer
    sku       = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.identifier[0].sku
    # Here I get the error: Error: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="The value of parameter imageReference.version is invalid." Target="imageReference.version"
  }
  
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "ga-win-gold-os-disk-1"
    caching           = "None"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
  }
  
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "ga-win-gold-1"
    admin_username = "svc"
    admin_password = var.WINDOWS_ADMIN_PASS
  }
  
  os_profile_windows_config {
    enable_automatic_upgrades = true
    provision_vm_agent        = true
  }
  
  storage_data_disk {
    name              = "ga-win-gold-data-disk-1"
    caching           = "None"
    create_option     = "Empty"
    disk_size_gb      = var.disk_size_gb
    lun               = 0
    managed_disk_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
  }
}
```

OR

```
data "azurerm_shared_image" "win19_gold_image" {
  provider            = azurerm.gi
  name                = "Windows-2019_base"
  gallery_name        = data.azurerm_shared_image_gallery.cap_win_gold_image_gallery.name
  resource_group_name = "gi-rg"
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "azure_win_runner" {
  provider                          = azurerm.og
  name                              = "vm-github-actions-win-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name               = data.azurerm_resource_group.dts_rg.name
  location                          = "East US"
  size                              = var.windows-vm-size
  count                             = "${var.number_of_win_az_instances}"
  network_interface_ids             = [
    azurerm_network_interface.azure_win_runner_nic[count.index].id,
  ]
  computer_name                     = "vm-ga-win-${count.index}"
  admin_username                    = var.windows-admin-username
  admin_password                    = var.WINDOWS_ADMIN_PASS

  os_disk {
    name = "vm-github-actions-win-${count.index}-os-disk"
    caching              = "None"
    storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.identifier[0].publisher
    offer     = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.identifier[0].offer
    sku       = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.identifier[0].sku
    version   = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.identifier[0].version # says this object does not have a version attached to it.
    # or version = "latest" or any other correct version string will throw error at time of apply that such a version does not exist.
  }

  enable_automatic_updates = true
  provision_vm_agent       = true
}
```

If I'm using `azurerm_virtual_machine` then if I ignore the version in `storage_image_reference` I receive the error:

```
Error: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="The value of parameter imageReference.version is invalid." Target="imageReference.version"
```

And if I add the version then I receive the error

```
Error: Unsupported attribute. 
This object does not have an attribute named "version".
```

When using `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` if I remove the version argument terraform complains that version is required and when provided a sting such as `1.0.0` or `latest`, while applying(terraform apply) it would complain that such a version does not exist.

And if I pull the version from `data.azurerm_shared_image.cap_win19_gold_image` it would complain that this object does not have a version.

I am confused as to how to use shared images for VM creation using terraform if version is mandatory yet if version is not available for azure shared images. Please advise on what am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sekhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi All who come across this question,

I found the solution to my issue. All I had to do was define a `azurerm_shared_image_version` data and then use `source_image_id` in `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` in place of `source_image_reference{}` block.

Below is what I did:

```
data "azurerm_shared_image_gallery" "win_gold_image_gallery" {
  provider            = azurerm.gi
  name                = "golden_image_gallery"
  resource_group_name = "gi-rg"
}

data "azurerm_shared_image" "win19_gold_image" {
  provider            = azurerm.gi
  name                = "Windows-2019_base"
  gallery_name        = data.azurerm_shared_image_gallery.win_gold_image_gallery.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_shared_image_gallery.win_gold_image_gallery.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_shared_image_version" "win19_gold_image_version" {
  provider            = azurerm.gi
  name                = "latest" # "recent" is also a tag to use the most recent image version
  image_name          = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.name
  gallery_name        = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.gallery_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "azure_win_gi_runner" {
  provider                          = azurerm.dep
  name                              = "vm-github-actions-win-gi-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name               = data.azurerm_resource_group.dts_rg.name
  location                          = "East US"
  size                              = var.windows-vm-size
  count                             = "${var.number_of_win_gi_az_instances}"
  network_interface_ids             = [
    azurerm_network_interface.azure_win_gi_runner_nic[count.index].id,
  ]
  computer_name                     = "ga-win-gi-${count.index}"
  admin_username                    = var.windows-admin-username
  admin_password                    = var.WINDOWS_ADMIN_PASS

  os_disk {
    name = "vm-github-actions-win-gi-${count.index}-os-disk"
    caching              = "None"
    storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
  }

  source_image_id = data.azurerm_shared_image_version.win19_gold_image_version.id 
# This is the thing I was missing.

  enable_automatic_updates = true
  provision_vm_agent       = true

  tags = {
    whichVM = var.gh_windows_runner
    environment = var.environment 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to get a version of the image you need to use another resource [1] and another data source [2]:

```
data "azurerm_image" "win19_gold_image" {
  name                = "Windows-2019_base"
  resource_group_name = "gi-rg"
}

resource "azurerm_shared_image_version" "win19_gold_image" {
  name                = "0.0.1"
  gallery_name        = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.gallery_name
  image_name          = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.resource_group_name
  location            = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.location
  managed_image_id    = data.azurerm_image.win19_gold_image.id
}
```

And then in the `source_image_reference` block in the `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` resource:

```
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.identifier[0].publisher
    offer     = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.identifier[0].offer
    sku       = data.azurerm_shared_image.win19_gold_image.identifier[0].sku
    version   = azurerm_shared_image_version.win19_gold_image.name
  }
```

As it seems the `name` argument is actually the version of the image [3]:

> name - (Required) The version number for this Image Version, such as 1.0.0. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/shared_image_version

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/image

[3] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/shared_image_version#name

Comment: Hi @marko-e, I tried out the above. But I do not have access to `gi-rg` resource group to use `azurerm_image`. I have requested the access to it. Though your answer looks viable. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Yeah, I tried parsing what the documents were telling me but I got confused by the `version` field where it's actually called `name` in a different resource.